# ORMLite alias in rawQuery

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite

Is it possible to use an alias (AS) in a query for ORMLite in Android? I am trying to use it with the following code:

```
String query =
        "SELECT *, (duration - elapsed) AS remaining FROM KitchenTimer ORDER BY remaining";
GenericRawResults<KitchenTimer> rawResults =
        getHelper().getKitchenTimerDao().queryRaw(
                query, getHelper().getKitchenTimerDao().getRawRowMapper());
```

But when this codes gets executed it gives the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown column name 'remaining' in table kitchentimer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown column name 'remaining' in table kitchentimer

The raw-row-mapper associated with your `KitchenTimerDao` expects the results to correspond directly with the `KitchenTimer` entity columns.  However, since you are adding your `remaining` column, it doesn't no where to put that result column, hence the exception.  This is a raw-query so you will need to come up with your own results mapper -- you can't use the DAO's.  See the [docs on raw queries](http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries).

For instance, if you want to map the results into your own object `Foo` then you could do something like:

```
String query =
    "SELECT *, (duration - elapsed) AS remaining FROM KitchenTimer ORDER BY remaining";
GenericRawResults<Foo> rawResults =
    orderDao.queryRaw(query, new RawRowMapper<Foo>() {
        public Foo mapRow(String[] columnNames, String[] resultColumns) {
            // assuming 0th field is the * and 1st field is remaining
            return new Foo(resultColumns[0], Integer.parseInt(resultColumns[1]));
        }
     });
// page through the results
for (Foo foo : rawResults) {
   System.out.println("Name " + foo.name + " has " + foo.remaining + " remaining seconds");
}
rawResults.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I wanted to get a list of objects but adding a new attribute with an alias.

To continue using the object mapper from OrmLite I used a RawRowMapper to receive columns and results. But instead of convert all columns manually I read the alias first and remove its reference in the column arrays. Then it is possible to use the OrmLite Dao mapper.

I write it in Kotlin code:

```
val rawResults = dao.queryRaw<Foo>(sql, RawRowMapper { columnNames, resultColumns ->

                // convert array to list
                val listNames = columnNames.toMutableList()
                val listResults = resultColumns.toMutableList()

                // get the index of the column not included in dao
                val index = listNames.indexOf(ALIAS)
                if (index == -1) {
                    // There is an error in the request because Alias was not received
                    return@RawRowMapper Foo()
                }

                // save the result
                val aliasValue = listResults[index]

                // remove the name and column
                listNames.removeAt(index)
                listResults.removeAt(index)

                // map row
                val foo = dao.rawRowMapper.mapRow(
                    listNames.toTypedArray(), 
                    listResults.toTypedArray()
                ) as Foo

                // add alias value. In my case I save it in the same object 
                // but another way is to create outside of mapping a list and 
                // add this value in the list if you don't want value and object together
                foo.aliasValue = aliasValue

                // return the generated object
                return@RawRowMapper foo
            })
```

It is not the shortest solution but for me it is very important to keep using the same mappers. It avoid errors when an attribute is added to a table and you don't remember to update the mapping.